# How to make Web API return all errors for the validated model?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1

ModelState returns only 1 error at a time when validation occurs. How to force Web API to return all errors at once.

```
 services.AddControllers()
            .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(setupAction =>
            {
                setupAction.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
                {
                      // context.ModelState here always contains only 1 error, even if I have more invalid fields in 
                }
            };
```

Comment: In `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` there is a constructor callled `ModelStateDictionary()` under this you would get [`ErrorCount `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary.errorcount?view=aspnetcore-5.0#definition) which can get you number of error but if you are expecting you would get all the error details together, you cannot do that. It will always fetch first one and terminates execution and entered to your custom `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` middleware.

Comment: Additonally you could try adding exception handler. You could [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler-lambda)

Comment: Thanks Farid, I suspected that - ErrorCount always one there

Comment: My pleasure to assist you on this

Comment: Is there anythig else that I can help you with? May I add the comment as an answer if it were helpful for you?

Comment: of course, plase add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your scenario, it can be said that,

In `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` there is a constructor callled `ModelStateDictionary()` under this you would get [`ErrorCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary.errorcount?view=aspnetcore-5.0#definition)  which can get you number of error.

But if you are expecting you would get all the error details together, you cannot do that. It will always fetch first one and terminates execution and entered to your custom `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` middleware.

> ***Note:*** So when any error encounters it terminates and return rather executing further as a results we always get first one. You
> could get our [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler-lambda)

Hope it would help you to guide you through.